# Set alert popup using jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using this code to change the required or not required property in a form mvc

```
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=Truefalse]").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("[id*=row]").hide();
                $("[id*=Annot]").prop("required", true);
            }
            else {
                $("[id*=row]").show();
            }
        });
    });
```

When the checkbox `True/False` is checked:

1. tDate hide;
2. Annot required

else

1. tDate show;
2. Annot not required

The code working correctly but if `True/False` is checked (*Annot required*) I need to open an alert popup when clicking on

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me?

My code below

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group" style="background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow; border:3px solid; font-weight:bold;">
            <h5 style="font-weight: bold; text-indent: 20px;">
                True/False @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Truefalse, true)
            </h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id =row class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.tDate)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.tDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @Class = "Mytextarea2", placeholder = "tDate" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.tDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Annot)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Annot, new { style = "width: 420px; height: 100px;", placeholder = "Annot" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

I've added a listener on the `.form-group .btn` element, then a property check on `[id*=Annot]` with a js `confirm()` when required.

```js
$(function () {
        $("[id*=Truefalse]").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("[id*=row]").hide();
                $("[id*=Annot]").prop("required", true);
            }
            else {
                $("[id*=row]").show();
            }
        });
        
        $(".form-group .btn").click(function () {
            if($("[id*=Annot]").prop("required") === true){
                confirm("Please confirm");
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group" style="background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow; border:3px solid; font-weight:bold;">
            <h5 style="font-weight: bold; text-indent: 20px;">
                True/False @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Truefalse, true)
            </h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id =row class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.tDate)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.tDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @Class = "Mytextarea2", placeholder = "tDate" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.tDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Annot)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Annot, new { style = "width: 420px; height: 100px;", placeholder = "Annot" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```